# Prometheus - add target specific label in static_configs

Tags: prometheus

I have job definition as follows:

```
  - job_name: 'test-name'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.1:9100', '192.168.1.1:9101', '192.168.1.1:9102' ]
        labels:
          group: 'development'
```

Is there any way to annotate targets with labels? For instance, I would like to add 'service-1' label to '192.168.1.1:9100', 'service-2' to '192.168.1.1:9101' etc.

Comment: upvoted because I didn't find any reference to this `labels` option in the scrap config [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config), am I alone ? :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I have the same question before. Here is my solution:

1. use job_name as the group label
2. add more target option to separate instance and add labels

For you the code may like this:

```
  - job_name: 'development'
      static_configs:
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.1:9100' ]
        labels:
          service: '1'
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.1:9101' ]
        labels:
          service: '2'
```

Comment: \*facepalm* I hadn't realized I could repeat targets and labels were specific to each like that.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 41):

Can be like this

```
  - job_name: 'node'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.117:9100']
      labels:
        instance: 'linux-ina'
    - targets: ['192.168.1.138:9100']
      labels:
        instance: 'linux-inb'
```

Tag name can be replaced with `instance`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For different services you should usually vary the job label, so I would suggest duplicating the scrape config with a job_name of service1 for one and service2 for the other.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but then it may be hard to manage multiple systems. I'd like to have two systems which will have the same services installed, the service names will be then duplicated:

  - job_name: 'service1'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.1:9100' ]
  - job_name: 'service2'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.1:9101' ]
  - job_name: 'service1'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.2:9100' ]
  - job_name: 'service2'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '192.168.1.2:9101' ]

What is the best solution for this, please?

Comment: https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus/
I think this is the solution which will work well for me. It seems that you've also written this blog post, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Brian's answer should be considered as correct. Imagine situation if you decide to relabel metrics for single target, using file_sd it is impossible without hacks and overcomplicating things. Anyone can say that you can use honor_labels, or temporal label for further rewriting but it is all dirty hacks you should avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File Based ServiceDiscovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config) to achieve this. See this [Blog Post](https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can find information in [here - Prometheus Good Config](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/config/testdata/conf.good.yml)

But I have used these and it worked

```
  - job_name:  'PostgreSQL-exporter'
    scrape_interval: 60s
    scrape_timeout: 60s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9187']
      - labels:
          name: value-for-the-name
```

Answer (score 1):

The targets do not have to be simple ip:port pairs, you can include extra info and use re-labelling to split out the ip and port from a nice instance name:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["157.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100@db56a", "176.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100@db56b"]
        labels:
          role: 'postgres_ha'
      - targets: ["46.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100@p1a", "176.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100@p1b", "136.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100@p1c"]
        labels:
          role: 'pulsar'
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
        regex: '(.*)@(.*)'
        replacement: $2
        target_label: instance
      - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
        regex: '(.*)@(.*)'
        replacement: $1
        target_label: __address__
```