# Adding Custom Attribute into Prometheus Metric such as Geolocation

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have many instances located at two different cities (İstanbul and Ankara)
I want to add the city location attribute automatically into all metrics coming from these instances
by indicating host in prometheus configuration. I have posted an example prometheus configuration. 
Is there a way of adding such custom attribute?

--Actual --

```
- job_name: 'my-app'
    scrape_interval: 60s
    metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets:
                 - 172.18.11.33:8081
                 - 172.18.11.34:8080
```

-- my expection added geolocation indicator--

```
job_name: 'my-app'
scrape_interval: 60s
metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
static_configs:
- targets:
- 172.18.11.33:8081;geo='istanbul’
- 172.18.11.34:8080;"geo='ankara'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [Prometheus - add target specific label in static_configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829423/prometheus-add-target-specific-label-in-static-configs)

You can define multiple targets:

```
static_configs:
  - targets: ['172.18.11.33:8081']
    labels:  {geo: 'istanbul'}
  - targets: ['172.18.11.34:8080']
    labels:  {geo: 'ankara'}
```